# Dragging an Image View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I am trying to drag an image view. I have got little bit of success in doing so, but it is not behaving as i want. I wish that it should move only if touch inside the image and drag it.
But it is moving even if I am touching and dragging from anywhere on the screen.

I have written code like this:

```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
         //retrieve touch point
      CGPoint pt= [[ touches anyObject] locationInView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];
      startLocation = pt; 

     }

    - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {

     CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];

     CGRect frame = [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]frame];
     frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
     frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
     [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame: frame];
```

}

Comment: Why you are accessing with `subviews`? You can have the instance of the imageview declared. And by checking whether you have touched the imageview by using `CGRectContainsPoint`.

Comment: when touchesBegan you can check whether your touch point is in your imageview or not

Comment: Is the frame of your image view set to cover the whole screen?

Comment: @robmayoff no, my image view is smaller than the whole screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of locationInView method is point relative to the view frame. check it is or not in the view frame first.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     CGRect targetFrame = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0].frame;
     //retrieve touch point
     CGPoint pt= [[ touches anyObject] locationInView:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];
     //check if the point in the view frame      
     if (pt.x < 0 || pt.x > targetFrame.size.width || pt.y < 0 || pt.y > targetFrame.size.height)
     {
         isInTargetFrame = NO;
     }
     else
     {
         isInTargetFrame = YES;
         startLocation = pt; 
     }
 }

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
      if(!isInTargetFrame)
      {
          return;
      }
      //move your view here...
}
```

Comment: its working.some modifications: frame is not a property, so send it as a message.And in if condition replace frame with targetFrame.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     //retrieve touch point
  startLocation = [[ touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
 // Now here check to make sure that start location is within the frame of 
 // your subview [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]
 // if it is you need to have a property like dragging = YES 
 // Then in touches ended you set dragging = NO

 }

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{

 CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];

 CGRect frame = [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]frame];
 frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
 frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
 [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame: frame];
```